# Which Sci-Fi work introduced "Bug-eyed Aliens"?

Tags: aliens, history-of

Although you can see Bug-eyed Aliens in modern times (Men in Black, for example), it was already out-dated in 60s. In a special episode of Doctor Who which featured making of Doctor Who, the producer didn't want to include Bug-eyed Monsters because they were out-dated at that time.

Which Sci-Fi work created Bug-eyed Aliens/Monsters?

Comment: Are you asking for the origin of the **phrase** "bug-eyed monster" (easy) or the **concept**, i.e., the first work to describe aliens as having eyes that bulge out (much harder question)?

Comment: As you probably know, the **expression** ["bug-eyed monster"](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/301) was coined by Martin Alger in a letter to *Thrilling Wonder Stories*, August 1939 issue, p. 121.

Comment: user14111, I suggest you submit that as the answer, unless OP asks for the concept.

It would be HS Wells that introduced the concept - in *The War of the Worlds*

Comment: @Jim2B The OP has not responded to requests for clarification, but I think the question must be about the **concept**, considering the OP's use of the variant form "bug-eyed **aliens**".

Comment: BEMs will be "out-dated" when real space aliens are discovered and found not to be bug-eyed. In other words, BEMs will never be out-dated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the OP has not provided a definition of "bug-eyed monster", we will go with the OED definition of "bug-eyed":

> Having bulging eyes; esp. in phr. **bug-eyed monster**, an extra-terrestrial monster with bulging eyes; abbrev. B.E.M.

So we are looking for early instances of **extra-terrestrial monsters with bulging eyes**.

Apparently it was the cover of the [June 1939 *Thrilling Wonder Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61728+c) that inspired the coinage of the phrase "bug-eyed monster" in a letter by Martin Alger in the next issue ([*Thrilling Wonder Stories*, August 1939](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61678+c)), according to the [Historical Dictionary of Science Fiction](https://sfdictionary.com/view/301). Alger wrote (see p. 121, column 2 at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v14n01_1939-08#page/n120/mode/1up)):

> Speaking of The SPWSSTFM, the cover inspired me to organize the SFTPOBEMOTCOSFP. (Society For The Prevention Of Bug-Eyed Monsters On The Covers Of Science-Fiction Publications.) Yours for complete novels and more civilized covers.

(By the way, the "SPWSSTFM" that Alger mentions is the [Society for the Prevention of Wire Staples in ScienTiFiction Magazines](http://fancyclopedia.org/first-staple-war), or something like that.)

Of course 1939 is nowhere near the beginning of BEMS in science fiction. As my answer to the question, I propose three covers from the first year of [*Amazing Stories*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Stories), namely, [Vol. 1, No. 2, May 1926](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56531+c), [Vol. 1, No. 4, July, 1926](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56397+c), and [Vol. 1, No. 7, October, 1926](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56624+c), all by the artist [Frank R. Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_R._Paul).

This is just a starting point for further research; no doubt earlier examples will be found. A commenter has suggested [*The War of the Worlds*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/36) (1897) by H. G. Wells, but I have doubts about that: Wells describes his Martians as having "large dark-coloured eyes", but I'm not sure they are especially bulgy.